# A question about derivative transforms

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives

Firstly I'm not sure "derivative transforms" is the correct statement. There is a question on my book: if $f : \Bbb R^n \mapsto\Bbb R $ and 
$v_q\in T_q(\Bbb R^n)$ then show that $f_*(v_q)=(v_q[f])\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{|_{f(q)}}}$

but isnt it supposed to be $f_*(v_q)=(v_q[f])\frac{\partial }{\partial y_{|_{f(q)}}}$

because we know $$\varphi_*(v_q)=\sum_{i=0}^m(v_q[f_i])\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{|_{{\varphi(q)}}}}$$.

$\varphi:\Bbb R^n \mapsto \Bbb R^m$ and respectivly $(x_1,x_2,x_3..,x_n)$ and $(y_1,y_2,y_3...,y_m)$ are cartesian coordinate systems in $\Bbb R^n $ and $\Bbb R^m$.

here we got m=1, $\varphi=f_1=f$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1{_{|_{{f(q)}}}}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{|_{{f(q)}}}}$ so it ll be $f_*(v_q)=(v_q[f])\frac{\partial }{\partial y_{|_{f(q)}}}$

Can you explain why it is x instead of y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of notation - the author has chosen here to use $x$ to denote the standard coordinate on $\mathbb R$, and thus $\partial/\partial x$ is the corresponding tangent vector; i.e. they mean by $x$ what you mean by $y$. Technically neither answer is correct without defining $x$ or $y$, but it is usually understood that the identity chart is used on $\mathbb R^n$ when no other is specified.